# remove some characters in a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I need to remove some characters in a data,frame and I dont know:

suppose we have the data.frame

```
       X1            X2
1  2:2.627488   3:3.507524  ...
2  2:4.734847   3:8.465927  ...
3  2:7.185827   3:12.939696 ...
4  2:6.923039   3:20.863585 ...
5  2:7.898322   3:19.106577 ...
.      .              .
.      .              .
.      .              .
```

how to remove "2:" ann  "3:" in R?

ie the data.frame looks like this:

```
      X1            X2
1   2.627488     3.507524  ...
2   4.734847     8.465927  ...
3   7.185827     12.939696 ...
4   6.923039     20.863585 ...
5   7.898322     19.106577 ...
.      .              .
.      .              .
.      .              .
```

Help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this also:

```
as.data.frame(gsub('[0-9]:', '', as.matrix(df)))
```

Comment: yes, assumed that you have a single decimal digit followed by a colon

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the pattern `\d+:` only occurs once, at the start of each entry in the data frame, then you can use `gsub()` to remove the unwanted prefix:

```
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) { x <- gsub("\\d+:", "", x) })
```